# Selenium IDE gotoif variable contains string?

Tags: javascript, variables, selenium, selenium-ide

and thanks for taking a look at this.

I've been working on a script that reads a web page, checking to see if a specified string of text is there, if not, it repeats the script. However, I have to paste every word of the string for the gotoif command to read it. Is there a way for gotoif to search for a variable to check if it CONTAINS a string?``

What I'm using for this is as follows

```
<tr>
    <td>gotoIf</td>
    <td>storedVars['activetext']=='This should trigger the gotoif'</td>
    <td>silencemethod</td>
</tr>
```

But, as described above, this only triggers the gotoif when the entire string is exactly as specified.

Answer (score 0):

gotoIf evaluates the next line as a JavaScript statement and checks for truth/falsity, so you can use something like

```
storedVars['activetext'].indexOf('some text') > -1
```

to see if "some text" was stored into activetext

Answer (score 0):

Using @MoldovanHipster's suggestion here is the full Selenium IDE code in an example:

Step 1: get a true or absent (false) message if eway is contained in the variable 'Name'

```
storeEval  
storedVars['Name'].indexOf('eway') > -1  
ewayYeah
```

Step 2: If we get a true value then let's head down to the 'eway' label

```
gotoIf  
'${ewayYeah}' == 'true'  
eway
```

Step 3: If the value is not true and is false we continue and get an alert

```
storeEval  
alert('This is NOT eway!')
```

Step 4: If the value did have 'eway' in the string then here is where we land, and have the appropriate alert

```
label  
eway   

storeEval  
alert('This is eway!')
```